# String to double currency has wrong result ( comma point issue)

Tags: c#, string, double, converters, currency

Now i have this problem here with comma and point in decimal point and thousands separator.

My program gets prices from different sources .

some american some european 
Some prices comes like this 2000,0.20 for 20000.20

and some like   2000.0,20 for again 20000.20

I couldn't find a way to make my code to recognize these two formats . 
i tried to use replace to turn the comma to dot but if there is thousands separator in the number i get problems. how can i convert string to double without these  kind of problems ?

I tried this 
but its just dont work if there is two different culture

```
            double.TryParse(price, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out priceD);
```

Comment: I dont know why asking a question would give me a downvote. i guess i have to go ahead and shut up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with

```
double FixUnknownCurrency(string amountText)
{
    amountText = amountText?.Trim()?.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(amountText))
        return 0d;  

    if(amountText.Length < 3)
        return double.Parse(amountText);

    var currencyDecimal = amountText[amountText.Length-3];
    if(Char.IsNumber(currencyDecimal))
        return double.Parse(amountText);

    if(currencyDecimal == '.' || currencyDecimal == ',')
    {
        amountText = amountText.Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace(".", string.Empty);
        return double.Parse(amountText) / 100d;
    }

    return double.Parse(amountText);
}
```

Try it out here. Running late for train: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTiL4s

Comment: it works for american and european . i just need to test eastern formats too to be sure. then im gonna set this post as solved. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a better way other than trying different cultures to see what succeeds.

Create a method like this:

```
public double CurrencyToDouble(string input)
{
    // Will hold the result
    double result = 0;

    // Try US culture
    if(double.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out result)) { return result; }

    // Try DE culture
    if (double.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), out result)) { return result; }

    // Try current system culture
    if(double.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result)) { return result; }

    // Try invariant culture
    if(double.TryParse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)) { return result; }

    // Try more common cultures...

    // Unsuccessful, throw some kind of error
    throw new FormatException("Could not convert!");
}
```

Input:

> CurrencyToDouble("2000,0.20");
>   CurrencyToDouble("2000.0,20");

Output:

> 20000.2
>   20000.2

Comment: from 116.9 i get 1169

Comment: Don't just copy and paste the code, learn why it does or does not work. In this case I assume your system culture is something other than en-US and so the number gets formatted incorrectly. I've added a line to try en-US first. You know where these APIs are located so you can add the correct cultures.